# sqlite3_step always returns SQLITE_DONE

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve data from a single table sqlite database, but (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) is always returning false. I've manually checked the database for the values and they're present. Here's the full code:

```
-(NSArray *)findByPartNumber:(NSString *)partNumber
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Description, ListPrice FROM PriceList WHERE PartNumber=?"];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [partNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *description;
                NSString *listPrice;

                const char *tmp1 = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                const char *tmp2 = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

                if(tmp1 == NULL)
                    description = nil;
                else
                {
                    description = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:tmp1];
                    [resultArray addObject:description];
                }
                if(tmp2 == NULL)
                    listPrice = nil;
                else
                {
                    listPrice = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:tmp2];
                    [resultArray addObject:listPrice];
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    if([resultArray count] == 0)
        return nil;
    else
        return resultArray;
}
```

The code enters the sqlite3_prepare_v2 block, but skips the sqlite3_step block. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out sqlite3_step was always returning SQLITE_DONE because there was no data. I had the databasePath set up incorrectly.

Incorrect code:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"databaseName.sqlite"]];
```

Correct code:

```
databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"databaseName" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is issue with your implementation.

You have written like:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [partNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
   ...
}
```

You can only bind values to prepared statements, so change the above code to:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
   sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [partNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've moved this line like you said and I'm still getting the same results. Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @mbeem: are you sure that the query is correct. Just execute it manually whether it works or not.

Comment: Any other thoughts? Looking around I've seen similar issues where the code is correct but the databased needed rebuilt. I'm not convinced that would fix my issue since I can manually query it, plus there are 1500 rows so I don't want to go through making it again...

Comment: @mbeem I think that bind_text cause issue. Instead of that, write a hardcoded query for the time-being and check whether it is working (No bind_text needed then), if it works issue is with bind_text call

Comment: @mbeem Can you share a sample database that have the same structure of your database with some dummy values in it?

Comment: This is the structure of the database: "CREATE TABLE 'PriceList' ('ID' INTEGER, 'PartNumber' TEXT, 'Description' TEXT, 'ListPrice' TEXT, 'MPCost' TEXT)". Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you so much, the sample project helped me find the issue which was actually in finding the path to the db, I'll post the fix as the answer.

Comment: I also did need to move the bind_text call like you originally suggested, so thanks for that too